# Morris bar chart not showing anything

Tags: html, bar-chart, morris.js

I have been trying to implement Morris bar chart but after running nothing is displayed. I am very much new to html/javascript and failed to understand the reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Morris.js Bar Chart Example</title>
<script>
    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'bar-example',
        data: [
            { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
            { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
            { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
            { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
            { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
            { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
            { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
        ],
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
        labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
    });
 </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bar-example"style="height: 250px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put your Morris code in a document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Morris Bar
});
```

Try this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'bar-example',
        data: [
            { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
            { y: '2007', a: 75, b: 65 },
            { y: '2008', a: 50, b: 40 },
            { y: '2009', a: 75, b: 65 },
            { y: '2010', a: 50, b: 40 },
            { y: '2011', a: 75, b: 65 },
            { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
        ],
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
        labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<div id="bar-example" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```